# Fast SQL checking for mutliple records

Tags: sql, database, jakarta-ee

May I ask that I have to perform checking on the userId column but the input may be more than 1.

**THE CONDITION**

I have to check whether the userId(input(s)) is one of the record inside the table or not.

**IF all of them inside the table**

SQL return 1

**IF one of them is NOT**

SQL return 0

I'm a newbie and what I can do is only

```
SELECT count(1) from users_roles where userid = ?
```

and using FOR loop in the java coding to insert the params and rerun this SQL.

Is there any other method or way i can do this with faster way? I'm thinking that if the input become more and more, it may take many resource to process it.

I'm a newbie in SQL. Sry for answer silly question.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select case when count(*) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as all_there
from users_roles
where userid in (?, ?, ?);
```

The `3` is equal to the number of parameters in the `in` list.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff     Thanks, haha  this is the solution that i wanted. Thanks so much ^_^. It solve all the problem. hehehehe XD